# Using XSLT to move element down

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML I need to rearange:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<application id="app_name">
  <display-name>app_name</display-name>

  <module id="epi-ejb-module">
    <ejb>appJar.jar</ejb>
  </module>

  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>awsi-client.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/awsi-client</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>

  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>other_war.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/some/path</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>

  ...

</application>
```

I need to move the awsi-client.war module to the last position, while keeping the rest of the document. My main difficulty is to distinguish between similarly named elements.

Any advice?

Comment: "I need" is not a question.

Comment: You are correct. Rephrasing, thank, you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="module[web/web-uri = 'awsi-client.war']" />

    <xsl:template match="module[last()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../module[web/web-uri = 'awsi-client.war']"/>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It uses the identity template and (1) omits outputting the module element containing `awsi-client.war` in its original position, and (2) matches on the last module element, copies it and then outputs the module containing the `awsi-client.jar` web-uri.

Comment: Thanks a lot, not just the answer but the explanation!